# foreach call member function on array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to display all menu's on my management panel.
I'm using a foreach loop to display all menu's entered in the database. Now I want to display the dishes with a foreach loop from another table within the foreach loop from the menu's.

Below you can find my foreach loop.

How am I able to put another foreach loop within the div 'panel-body' getting the data from $menu['ID']
Whenever i try to do so I'm getting Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_menu_items() on array in
How can I call a member function on an array?

```
 <?php foreach($menus as $menu): ?>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
           <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-test" href="#<?php echo $menu['ID'] ?>" class="collapsed">
                          <?php echo $menu['title'] ?>
                     </a>
                </h4>
           </div>
           <div id="<?php echo $menu['ID'] ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                     <a href="deletemenu.php?id=<?php echo $menu['ID'] ?>">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light w-xs m-b-5 pull-right" >Verwijder</button>
                     </a>
                     <a href="editmenu.php?id=<?php echo $menu['ID'] ?>">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light w-xs m-b-5 pull-right" style="margin-right: 5px;">Bewerken</button>
                     </a>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>


public function get_menu_items($id)
{
  try
  {
      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM menu_items WHERE menu_id=:menu_id");
      $stmt->execute(array(':menu_id' => $id));
      $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      return $result;
  }
  catch (PDOException $e)
  {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }

}

public function get_menu()
{
  try
  {
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY ID");
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
  }
  catch (PDOException $e)
  {
      echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: please put your full code

Comment: Display the dishes?

Comment: I've added both functions used to get this done. I hope it's enough

Comment: where are you calling the get_menu_items();

Comment: That's my whole problem. I tried to do it within the foreach loop since it has to get the ID from there, but it gives me the error:Call to a member function get_menu_items() on array
I'm sorry if my English isn't that great

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? How did you try to call the method?